# Find & match words in uppercase followed by a colon (":")

Tags: windows

How can I find and match only text (letters) that is in uppercase, before a colon (followed by `:`) and replace it with a single name ("MyName")?

I also want to make a color text, but I don't know how to add for all uppercase (letters) followed by a colon (`:`) only this color scheme, without modifying the person name.

Example:

```
MIKE: - Go to school!

VICTORIA: Yes, I go right now.
```

to

```
< font color="#800080">MIKE:</font> - Go to school!

< font color="#800080">VICTORIA:</font> Yes, I go right now.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell solution:

```
Get-Content "file.txt" |
ForEach-Object { $_ -CReplace "[A-Z]+:", "MyName" } |
Set-Content "file.txt"
```

Quick explanation:

- [`Get-Content`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849787.aspx) retrieves the contents of the specified file. The pipe character (`|`) passes the result to the next command.
- [`ForEach-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849731.aspx) loops over the file's contents line by line, and for each line (represented by `$_`) replaces the text given as the first parameter with the text given as the second parameter. `[A-Z]+:` is a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info), searching for one or more (`+`) uppercase letters (`[A-Z]`) followed by a colon. `-CReplace` is used for case sensitive searching, because regular expressions in PowerShell are case-insensitive by default.
- [`Set-Content`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849828.aspx) is the opposite of `Get-Content`, writing the input back to the given file.

I split the code up to several lines for readability, but you can write it all on one line. Using [aliases](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692685.aspx) you can even shorten it considerably:

```
gc "file.txt" | % { $_ -creplace "[A-Z]+:", "MyName" } | sc "file.txt"
```

If you want to actually modify each match, rather than replace it with a fixed text, then try the following:

```
Get-Content "file.txt" |
ForEach-Object { $_ -CReplace "([A-Z]+:)", '<font color="#800080">$1</font>' } |
Set-Content "file.txt"
```

Notice two changes from the previous version:

- The regular expression `[A-Z]+:` is surrounded by parentheses. This creates a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), which we later refer to in the replacement text as `$1`. This is how you keep the text you were searching for in the result, rather than replacing it.
- Single quotes around the replacement text. If you used double quotes, PowerShell would try to interpret the `$1` as a variable, which doesn't exist, and would return nothing where you'd expect the name to be. Also, single quotes are handy when the text contains double quotes (as is the case with HTML), because you don't have to escape each double quote with a backtick.

Comment: Thanks a lot!

But if I want to make a color text, how to add for all UPPERCASE (letters) followed by (':') only this color scheme.

For ex:
"MIKE: - Go to school!"
"< font color="#800080">MIKE:< /font> - Go to school!"

Comment: @cipry See updated answer.

Comment: @cipry You're welcome. Do feel free to upvote the answer if it helped you, and mark it as accepted (by clicking the green checkmark next to it) if it solved your problem.

Comment: Yes your updated post help me a lot.I figure how it's work: I make a txt file with your code, I rename it to .ps1 then I run it with admin right,but i get un error.Was a powershell problem and I write in a cmd windows "set-executionpolicy remotesigned" and then all work great.

Comment: @cipry Yes, by default PowerShell only permits running commands directly in the PS prompt. The command you typed in enables running PS script files, but also requires files downloaded from the Internet to be signed. It's a reasonable compromise between the restrictive default and permitting absolutely all code to run.

Comment: One more question: if the Uppercase name is of two or more words, how can replace it with that color scheme.EX: "MARY (OF CASTLE): Go shopping!"... thanks a lot again.

Comment: Never mind sir.I figured out : [A-Z'\s|,]+:

Comment: But if I want to make 2 variable : "[A-Z'\s|,]+:"  and "(\([^\(\)]*\))" in a same script with 2 different color scheme. EX: set var1= "[A-Z'\s|,]+:" and set var2="(\([^\(\)]*\))"

Comment: @cipry You can just repeat the `-CReplace` parameter (with the two strings following it) for each replacement you want to make. Also, if you haven't done so already, check out the [regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info) I linked to in my answer - if you're going to be doing this sort of text processing often, having a good grasp of regular expressions comes in very handy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Indreks answer modified as

```
  -replace "([A-Z]:)", "<font color='#800080'>$1</font>"
```

or better

```
  -replace "([A-Z]:)", "<span class='name'>$1</span>"
```

and then add to your CSS

```
  span.name { color:#800080; }
```

Untested, you may need to use `\` to "escape" characters that are reserved characters in powershell.

Powershell is a good choice because you almost certainly already have it on your Windows computer.

I have no incentive to learn Powershell because it is so easy to install Perl (and/or GNU file utils including sed awk grep etc)

Using perl the solution would be something like

```
 perl -p -i -e 's/[A-Z]+:/<span class="name">$&</span>' f1.txt zz.txt b/c/*.txt
```

(I find this simpler than powershell but I am biased)